# Как правильно написать rule для RBAC?

Tags: php, yii2

yii2-advanced, использую RBAC, необходимо настроить доступ групп пользователей к редактированию групп продуктов У аккаунта каждого пользователя есть поле `brand_id`; такое же поле есть и у продуктов.

Нужно было сделать проверку этих полей. Сделал максимально просто и тупо.

Контроллер:

```
    if (Yii::$app->user->can('updateFabricatorImages', ['brand_id' => $model->brand_id])) {
        //код редактирования
    }
```

Rule:

```
public function execute($user, $item, $params)
{
    if (Yii::$app->user->can('moderator')) {
        return true;
    }
    $model = Users::findOne(Yii::$app->user->id);
    return isset($params['brand_id']) ? $model->brand_id == $params['brand_id'] : false;
}
```

Наверное на этом можно и остановиться, но мне интересно, как правильно оформить правило, т.е. без лишнего запроса в базу? Или по-другому никак?

Comment: Запрос в базу не обязательно делать. 
У вас инфа о текущем пользователе лежит в 

Yii::$app->user->identity->brand_id (Как-то так)

Comment: @abakan, спасибо. а я то думал, в чем подвох... писал такой же запрос, но без identity. я так понимаю там лежит вся инфа о текущем пользователе, в тч и поля типа пароля и почты?

Comment: В  Yii::$app->user->identity полностью модель текущего юзера лежит со всеми атрибутами, с почтой и паролем в том числе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(ответ из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/883118/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-rule-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-rbac?noredirect=1#comment1437534_883118) )
Запрос в базу не обязательно делать. У вас инфа о текущем пользователе лежит в Yii::$app->user->identity->brand_id
(Как-то так)